# How to create LEGO mountainous landscape?

Tags: mesh

I wanted to create a LEGO landscape based on the LEGO Movie's way of doing it. I've tried turning a LEGO fluid simulation from a tutorial into a stagnant landscape, without any results. Here is an example picture of a desert scene from The LEGO Movie:[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I need! I was searching strictly using the term LEGO and didn't think to use cubes! Thank you!

Comment: you can also use a particle system with one particle per face to add the cylinders on top